# In terms of time complexity, what is the most efficient way to overlay multiple smaller images onto a bigger image?

Tags: image, performance, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to overlay multiple smaller images onto a bigger background image using openCV. Currently I am using `addWeighted()` API with alpha=1.0 but this API only takes in two images.

If img1 is overlaid onto img2 which is in turn overlaid onto img3, then I would have to call addWeighted() multiple times and the time complexity will be O(total_number_pixels_in_all_smaller_images).

Is there a way I can achieve this with time complexity = O(no_of_pixels_in_final_image) ?

Comment: Can you please show some code, how you currently use `addWeighted()`?

Comment: Each pixel of each overlay influences the result, and so will involve one multiplication and one addition. | Practically, there are probably some opportunities to optimize your code -- but to give any meaningful hints, we'll need to see it first.